# Orthogonal representation - Weyl decomposition

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, orthogonality, divergence-operator

## Setting of the problem

Let $Q \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ a regular bounded domain. We denote

$$L^2_{sol}(Q)=\{v \in (L^2(Q))^2 \ | \ \int_Q v \cdot \nabla \varphi \ \mathrm{d}x=0 \quad \forall \varphi \in (H^1_0(Q))^3 \}$$
and
$$L^2_{pot}(Q)=\{v \in (L^2(Q))^d \ | \ \int_Q  v_j \partial_i  \varphi - v_i \partial_j \varphi \ \mathrm{d}x=0, \quad \forall \varphi \in H^1_0(Q), \quad  1 \leq i,j \leq d \}$$
i.e  the space of $L^2(Q)$ vector with $div_{H^{-1}(Q)}=0$ and $rot_{H^{-1}(Q)}=0$ respectively. We also denote $\nu^2_{pot}(Q)$ the functions of $L^2_{pot}(Q)$ with zero average on $Q$.
It is well known that the following orthogonal representation holds :

$$(L^2(Q))^d= \nu^2_{pot}(Q) \oplus L^2_{sol}(Q)$$

## My question

I was wondering if there exists a similar decomposition for the space

$$A= \{v \in (L^2(Q))^2 \ | \ \int_Q v \cdot \nabla \varphi \ \mathrm{d}x=0 \quad \forall \varphi \in (H^1(Q))^3 \}$$
which is almost the same as $L^2_{sol}(Q)$ except the test function are now in $(H^1(Q))^3$ rather than $(H^1_0(Q))^3$ . I'm also wondering why would one consider $A$ rather than $L^2_{sol}(Q)$ as a functional space.

Any suggestion is welcomed !